# FFmpeg AVERROR(EAGAIN) error when call avcodec receive for h264

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, decoding

I'm working with ffmpeg 4.1 and I'm showing live streams of multiple cameras, h264 and h265.

*My program collects packets of the same frame and then calls decodeVideo function. Actually it sends all packets of a frame at once.*

Program works well if there is no missing packets. When I remove packet in random I-frames, both h264 and h265 streams work as expected (jumps some seconds but continues streaming).

When I remove packet in random P-frame from h265 streams, avcodec_send_packet function gives AVERROR_INVALIDDATA and streams continue.

However when I remove packet in random P-frame from h264 streams, avcodec_send_packet function gives 0. Then avcodec_receive_frame function gives AVERROR(EAGAIN) continuously and streams freeze.

```cpp
void decodeVideo(array<uint8_t>^ data, int length, AvFrame^ finishedFrame)
{   
    AVPacket* videoPacket = new AVPacket();
    av_init_packet(videoPacket);
    pin_ptr<unsigned char> dataPtr = &data[0];
    videoPacket->data = dataPtr;
    videoPacket->size = length;             

    int retVal = avcodec_send_packet((AVCodecContext*)context, videoPacket);
    if(retVal < 0)
    {
        if (retVal == AVERROR_EOF)
            Utility::Log->ErrorFormat("avcodec_send_packet() return value is AVERROR_EOF.");
        else if( retVal == AVERROR_INVALIDDATA)
            Utility::Log->ErrorFormat("avcodec_send_packet() INVALID DATA!");
        else
            Utility::Log->ErrorFormat("avcodec_send_packet() return value is negative:{0}",retVal);
    }
    else
    {                   
        int receive_frame = avcodec_receive_frame((AVCodecContext*)context, (AVFrame*)finishedFrame);

        if (receive_frame == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
            Utility::Log->ErrorFormat("avcodec_receive_frame() returns AVERROR(EAGAIN)");
        else if(receive_frame == AVERROR_EOF)
            Utility::Log->ErrorFormat("avcodec_receive_frame() returns AVERROR(AVERROR_EOF)");
        else
            Utility::Log->ErrorFormat("avcodec_receive_frame() return value is negative:{0}",receive_frame);
    }   

    av_packet_unref(videoPacket);
    delete videoPacket;
}
```

## EDIT

When I add `avcodec_flush_buffers` like shown, my problem is temporarily solved. However it freeze again after a while.

```cpp
if(receive_frame == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
{
    Utility::Log->ErrorFormat("avcodec_receive_frame() returns AVERROR(EAGAIN)");
    avcodec_flush_buffers((AVCodecContext*)context);
}
```

*Tested with ffmpeg version 4.1.1 same results.*

*Find an ffmpeg version like 2.5 decode function is different but there is no problem when i remove packets. However I'm working with h265 streams too.*

**EDIT2**

```cpp
AVCodecID id = AVCodecID::AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
AVCodec* dec = avcodec_find_decoder(id);
AVCodecContext* decContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(dec);
```

After these lines, my code included the following lines. *When i delete them, there is no problem now.*

```cpp
if(dec->capabilities & AV_CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED)
    decContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_TRUNCATED;

decContext->flags2 |= AV_CODEC_FLAG2_CHUNKS;
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @szatmary thx for advice, decode function is added